# What is the most efficient way to print a linked list?

Tags: java, printing, linked-list

Lets say I have a linked list of strings. What is the most efficient way to print this linked list?

Comment: There's really only one way to skin this cat, and that's your most straightforward linear walk.

Answer (score 1):

Same as with any list or array: Loop over the elements and print each in turn. O(n).

Answer (score 1):

@Thilo is correct.  The obvious solution is the correct one ... provided that you don't format the string in a pessimal fashion (e.g. by appending to one big string), or implicitly flush the output too much.

---

But the other thing that needs to be said is this:

> Don't obsess over performance / efficiency.

Most of the time, the performance / efficiency of something like this doesn't matter.  And in this case, unless you do something seriously wrong the time taken of formatting the list is likely to be small relative to the time taken of outputting the characters, and TINY compared to the time taken to run the entire program.

And there is a fair chance that you are actually spending more time *thinking about* this problem than will be saved ... for end users waiting for the computer to give them the answer.

Performance *can* be important.  But it is unlikely to be important here.  It is better to only spend effort on making things faster when you have *evidence* that the effort is needed.  Get the program working first, profile it, *and only then* decide if there is any value in optimizing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert the `LinkedList` to an array (using `.toArray(new String[0])`) and then print it using [Arrays.deepToString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

```
Arrays.deepToString(convertedArray);
```

Comment: Why would that be more efficient than other methods? And why do you need `deepToString` with a non-deep object like a String?

Answer (score 0):

The Java collections implement optimized iterators, specific to the data structure. Specifically to `LinkedList`, the iterator keeps a pointer to the last returned element to allow constant time `next()` and `previous()` operations.

In another hand, if you want to print to console each element, the best way is using a buffer.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out, false); // autoFlush false
// for-each or iterator
//     out.print(obj);
out.flush(); // flush to the output
```

If you use only `System.out`, each operation is then sent immediately to the output, which can be slow. Did you see that disable or change the log level in some app servers for better performance?